# What is so good about countdown latch?

Tags: java, scala, concurrency

```
object Main extends App {
  val poolSize = 2
  val executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize)
  val doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(poolSize)
  (0 until poolSize).foreach{
    i => executor.submit(new Work(doneSignal, i))
  }
  executor.shutdown()
  println("Work submitted")
  doneSignal.await()
  println("Work completed")
}

class Work(doneSignal:CountDownLatch, id:Int) extends Runnable {
  override def run(): Unit = {
    println(s"Starting $id : ${Thread.currentThread().getName}")
    Thread.sleep(3000)
    println(s"Ending $id : ${Thread.currentThread().getName}")
    doneSignal.countDown()
  }
}
```

I appreciate that CountDownLatch is a threadsafe class that can help with inter thread communication. But for the use case as shown above won't a simple

```
executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
```

suffice?

Comment: What are you doing here with doneSignal? Do you mean replace awaitTermination with doneSignal.await()?

Comment: yeah you are right, made changes to code

Comment: Don't think it would make any difference in this example but if you had code in Work after doneSignal.countDown() then it would be different.

Comment: i thought the whole idea is for doneSignal.countDown() to be called after all work has been done

Comment: See my response - countDown() should be called after the action that requires synchronization is completed which may or may not coincide with thread completion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example there should be no difference in using either.

> A CountDownLatch initialized to N can be used to make one thread wait
>   until N threads have completed some action or some action has been completed N times.

It is not required that the threads complete execution - just that they complete some action as dictated by your synchronization requirements - they indicate that completion using latch.countDown();

For **example** *if you are fetching data from 5 web services before rendering your UI you could do that in separate threads. Once data is available the rendering can begin but your individual threads make still continue execution to perform some bookkeeping operations for that data.*

The ExecutorService.awaitTermination() requires that the threads complete execution. In your case they would work similar but in the following example they wouldn't.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        int count = 2;
        ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(5);
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
            ex.execute(() -> {
                String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                System.out.println("Starting thread "+ name);
                try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (Exception e) { }
                System.out.println("Pre-Notification work completed "+ name);
                latch.countDown();
                try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (Exception e) { }
                System.out.println("Post-Notification Work Completed"+ name);
            }
        );
        latch.await();
        //ex.shutdown();
        //ex.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        System.out.println("Finishing Execution");
    }
}
```

Output with latch.await

```
Starting thread pool-1-thread-1
Starting thread pool-1-thread-2
Pre-Notification work completed pool-1-thread-1
Pre-Notification work completed pool-1-thread-2
Finishing Execution
Post-Notification Work Completedpool-1-thread-1
Post-Notification Work Completedpool-1-thread-2
```

Output with awaitTermination

```
Starting thread pool-1-thread-2
Starting thread pool-1-thread-1
Pre-Notification work completed pool-1-thread-2
Pre-Notification work completed pool-1-thread-1
Post-Notification Work Completedpool-1-thread-1
Post-Notification Work Completedpool-1-thread-2
Finishing Execution
```

Comment: I see, thank you very much for the detailed explanation :)